# How to pass arguments into an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a suggestion command where the user would type `.suggest <yoursuggestion>` and it would send an embed with their suggestion to a suggestions channel for people to vote on.
The only issue I'm having right now is that each argument (word), is taking up its own line and I don't want that to happen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['suggestion'],
    description: 'Sends a suggestion to the <#700591796119535657> channel.',
    usage: '<your suggestion>',
    cooldown: 1,
    args: true,
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#32CF67')
            .setTitle('Suggestion:')
            .setDescription(args)
            .attachFiles(['/home/shares/public/RetroCraft/retro.png'])
            .setThumbnail('attachment://retro.png')
            // .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true }));

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
        channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed }).then(embedMessage => {
            embedMessage.react('710672162242953266')
                .then(() => embedMessage.react('710672162393948170'))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react('710672162264055808'))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react('710672162343747607'))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react('710672162125643837'))
                .then(() => embedMessage.react('710672162171650058'))
                .catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));
        });
    },
};
```

This is how the args command is defined in my index.js:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
```

This is the resulting message when I run `.suggest this is a test`

[image: The resulting message when I do <code>.suggest this is a test</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you passing `args`, which is an array and not a string, to the `.setDescription()` method.
To fix this you can join the array of words with spaces:

```js
exampleEmbed.setDescription(args.join(' '))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Clearly too late at night for me to think straight, shoulda realized I was trying to directly pass an array into the message.

Comment: Don't worry ahaha